# Thresholding of probabilities in a binary classification

Tags: python, numpy, classification

I am struggling to compute the class label in a simple binary classification problem, given by 2d-numpy array with probabilities for each class.

**For example:**

```
prob_01 = 
array([[ 0.49253953,  0.50746047],
       [ 0.01041495,  0.98958505],
       [ 0.76774408,  0.23225592],
       ..., 
       [ 0.79755047,  0.20244953],
       [ 0.27228677,  0.72771323],
       [ 0.26953926,  0.73046074]])
```

where the rows are instances and the columns contain probabilities of being in the class 0 and 1 respectively for each instance. For example, for a `threshold = 0.5`, one should get:

```
labels_01= 
array([[ 1],
       [ 1],
       [ 0],
       ..., 
       [ 1],
       [ 0],
       [ 0]])
```

What is the simplest and pythonic way to produce the `labels_01` array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the class 0 (first column):

```
threshold = 0.5
labels_01 = prob_01[:,0] < threshold
```

To actually get integers instead of booleans (presuming `import numpy as np`):

```
labels_01 = (prob_01[:,0] < threshold).astype(np.int)
```

Or just use

```
prob_01 < threshold
```

to get both columns at once and index a column later.

Comment: wow, so simple! I completely missed off to se only one columns. Thanks.